# [flink]Task manager initialization failed

Tags: apache-flink

I am new to flink. I am trying to run the flink example on my local PC(windows).

However, after I run the start-cluster.bat, I login to the dashboard, it shows the task manager is 0.

I checked the log and seems it fails to initialize:

```
2020-02-21 23:03:14,202 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       - TaskManager initialization failed.
org.apache.flink.configuration.IllegalConfigurationException: Failed to create TaskExecutorResourceSpec
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutorResourceUtils.resourceSpec.FromConfig(TaskExecutorResourceUtils.java:72)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.startTaskManager(TaskManagerRunner.java:356)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.<init>(TaskManagerRunner.java:152)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.runTaskManager(TaskManagerRunner.java:308)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.lambda$runTaskManagerSecurely$2(TaskManagerRunner.java:322)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.runTaskManagerSecurely(TaskManagerRunner.java:321)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.main(TaskManagerRunner.java:287)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.configuration.IllegalConfigurationException: The required configuration option Key: 'taskmanager.cpu.cores' , default: null (fallback keys: []) is not set
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutorResourceUtils.checkConfigOptionIsSet(TaskExecutorResourceUtils.java:90)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutorResourceUtils.lambda$checkTaskExecutorResourceConfigSet$0(TaskExecutorResourceUtils.java:84)
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutorResourceUtils.checkTaskExecutorResourceConfigSet(TaskExecutorResourceUtils.java:84)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutorResourceUtils.resourceSpecFromConfig(TaskExecutorResourceUtils.java:70)
... 7 more
2020-02-21 23:03:14,217 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.TransientBlobCache              - Shutting down BLOB cache
```

Basically, it looks like a required option 'taskmanager.cpu.cores' is not set. However, I can't find this property in flink-conf.yaml and in the document(https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/ops/config.html) either.

I am using flink 1.10.0. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That configuration option is intended for internal use only -- it shouldn't be user configured, which is why it isn't documented.

The windows start-cluster.bat is failing because of a bug introduced in Flink 1.10. See https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-15925.

One workaround is to use the bash script, start-cluster.sh, instead.

See also this mailing list thread: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r7693d0c06ac5ced9a34597c662bcf37b34ef8e799c32cc0edee373b2%40%3Cdev.flink.apache.org%3E

Comment: Thx! Really appreciate!