# Apace Flink : Task Manager failed to start

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, java-11

I'm trying to start flink (v1.15.0) on local (Win 10 platform) as a standalone cluster but the task manager fails to start as a result the number of task slots available is zero.

Have already followed links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645093/apache-flink-available-task-slots-0) one but the issue still persists.

Please find the logs as follows :

> ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '30946e09' at 'null' in 'null'
> ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '3e2059ae' at 'null' in 'null'
> 22:11:46.825 [main] **ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner - Terminating TaskManagerRunner with exit code 1.
> org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Failed to start the TaskManagerRunner**.
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.runTaskManager(TaskManagerRunner.java:483) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.lambda$runTaskManagerProcessSecurely$5(TaskManagerRunner.java:525) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.runTaskManagerProcessSecurely(TaskManagerRunner.java:525) [flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.runTaskManagerProcessSecurely(TaskManagerRunner.java:505) [flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.main(TaskManagerRunner.java:463) [flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> **Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not create the working directory C:\Users\mohile\AppData\Local\Temp\tm_localhost:56106-13fd70**.
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.WorkingDirectory.createDirectory(WorkingDirectory.java:58) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.WorkingDirectory.(WorkingDirectory.java:39) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.WorkingDirectory.create(WorkingDirectory.java:88) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypointUtils.lambda$createTaskManagerWorkingDirectory$0(ClusterEntrypointUtils.java:152) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.DeterminismEnvelope.map(DeterminismEnvelope.java:49) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypointUtils.createTaskManagerWorkingDirectory(ClusterEntrypointUtils.java:150) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.startTaskManagerRunnerServices(TaskManagerRunner.java:210) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.start(TaskManagerRunner.java:288) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.runTaskManager(TaskManagerRunner.java:481) ~[flink-dist-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> ... 5 more
> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jboss.netty.util.internal.ByteBufferUtil (file:/C:/Users/mohile/AppData/Local/Temp/flink-rpc-akka_38e8d879-8c2e-46b3-8ff6-163f77c989d6.jar) to method java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.cleaner()
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jboss.netty.util.internal.ByteBufferUtil
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Any help appreciated..

Comment: Looks like someone else had the same issue (see the Flink mailing list thread [1]). Windows cannot work with colons in the path. Please update the `taskmanager.resource-id` using no special characters to work around the issue as suggested by in the ML thread.

[1] https://lists.apache.org/thread/1542b2q87ol1b7wmy1jh6drp6q3prvsb